# How to find the missing terms

Tags: linear-algebra, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, negative-binomial

Consider the product series:

$(x-a)$ $(x^{2} -b)$ .......$(x^{14} -n)$

I want to express the result in this form:

$x^{1+2+3+.....14}$ + (some constant)$x^{1+2+3+...14-1}$ +.......so on

My question is how to find the general expression for the coefficients for every powers of x(which are decreasing)?

I have no idea please help me

Is there any formula which can help me?

Comment: I would start with setting $a, b, \ldots,n$ to $1$ first and see what you get. Then set them all to $-1$, and see what you get. That's difficult enough, and at the same time ought to give you a good idea of how to attack the general problem.

Comment: @Arthur Yes I completely understand but I need to express it in decreasing powers of x and all I want is some formula or generalization for it's respective coefficients

Comment: @Arthur I think setting them to 1 is an assumption sir. Can't we do it without any assumption?

Comment: You are entirely correct that it is an assumption. As I said, I thiunk you should do it with some restrictive assumptions first, just to see what happens. Then once you've done that, you can try to do the whole thing.

Comment: @Arthur But sir in that case the whole question will become different. But I want to thank you for giving me the idea...Hope someone solves it

Comment: I'm telling you that I think the fastest way for you to appreciate and understand your problem is to solve my problem first.

Comment: @Arthur okay so i should try by setting all constants like a,b,.....n =1 right?

Comment: @Arthur let me see wait

Comment: @Arthur Yes successfully done, i mean your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a general formula.  You know that the leading term is $x^105$ because $\sum_{k=1}^{14}{k}=105.$  Now the next term must be $-ax^{104}$ because there's only one way to get $x^{104}.$ Similarly, the third term is $-bx^{103}.$  But when we get to $x^{102}$ things change.  We might have multiplied all the variables but $x^3$ or all the variables but $x$ and $x^2$, so the coefficient is $ab-c$.  Things will get more complicated as you go along.  There are $2^{14}=16,384$ ways to pick which constants to multiply together, and only 106 terms among which to distribute the products, so it's going to get messy.

May I ask why you want to know the individual terms?  It seems like you've got a pretty simple formula now.

Comment: Sir, I want to know it because I require it for a problem in my exercise

Comment: I still believe there can be some way sir

Comment: David, there has to be something more to this problem.  This would be far too arduous as an exercise.  No teacher would make you compute 16,000 terms -- he wouldn't be able to grade it!  What exactly is the problem statement?

Comment: It was given as a bounty problem. I guess we need to invent some formula for it if it is possible. The problem was the same written here. I just want to devise some formula not because of the reward but because of the love for mathematics

Comment: I wish you good luck, but I'm not optimistic.

Comment: thanks sir for wishing me